# How to pre-select items in Select2 component in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-select2

I've got a Select2 component built off the [Vuejs documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

However it doesn't tell you how to pre-load the selections when creating the component.

I've got the following component:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="select2-template">
    <select>
        <slot></slot>
    </select>
</script>
<script id="defaultSelect2Component">
    text_truncate = function (str, length, ending) {
        if (length == null) {
            length = 25;
        }
        if (ending == null) {
            ending = '...';
        }
        if (str.length > length) {
            return str.substring(0, length - ending.length) + ending;
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    };
    function dataToSelect2Format(subdomains) {
        return subdomains.map((subdomain) => ({
            id: subdomain.id,
            text: (subdomain.character_code + ": " + text_truncate(subdomain.short_description))
        }));
    }
    const select2Component = Vue.component("select2", {
        props: ["options", "value"],
        template: "#select2-template",
        mounted: function () {
            var vm = this;
            $(vm.$el)
                // init select2
                .select2({
                    data: dataToSelect2Format(vm.options),
                    placeholder: "Select Subdomains"
                })
                .val(vm.value)
                .trigger("change")
                // emit event on change.
                .on("change", function () {
                    vm.$emit("input", $(this).val());
                });

        },
        watch: {
            options: function (options) {
                // update options
                $(this.$el)
                    .empty()
                    .select2({data: dataToSelect2Format(options)});
            }
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $(this.$el)
                .off()
                .select2("destroy");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is how I'm initializing it:

```
                                <select2
                                        ref="subdomains"
                                        name="subdomains"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        id="itemSubdomains"
                                        :options="option_subdomains"
                                        multiple="multiple"
                                        v-model="subdomains">
                                    <option></option>
                                </select2>
```

I use this component inside other Vue components, so I'm not sure where or how to set the pre-selected items in this select2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you already have `subdomains` for that? Just assign initial values to `subdomains` and that's it.

Comment: I've tried doing that a number of different ways without success.

Comment: Do `id`s have a string type? Did you assign `subdomains` an array of ids?

Comment: I had to write some little helper scripts to convert the selections to/from the arrays that select2 was expecting, it's working now - you sent me in exactly the direction I needed to go! Thank you!